# Java equivalent of python's String partition

Tags: java, python, string, split

Java's string split(regex) function splits at all instances of the regex.  Python's partition function only splits at the first instance of the given separator, and returns a tuple of {left,separator,right}.

How do I achieve what partition does in Java?

e.g.

```
"foo bar hello world".partition(" ")
```

should become

```
"foo", " ", "bar hello world"
```

- Is there an external library which
  provides this utility already?
- how would I achieve it without
  an external library?
- And can it be achieved without an external library and without Regex?

NB. I'm not looking for split(" ",2) as it doesn't return the separator character.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`String.split(String regex, int limit)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) is close to what you want. From the documentation:

> The `limit` parameter controls the number of times the pattern is applied and therefore affects the length of the resulting array.
>
> - If the limit `n` is greater than zero then the pattern will be applied at most `n - 1` times, the array's length will be no greater than `n`, and the array's last entry will contain all input beyond the last matched delimiter.
> - If `n` is non-positive then the pattern will be applied as many times as possible and the array can have any length.
>
>   - If `n` is zero then the pattern will be applied as many times as possible, the array can have any length, and *trailing empty strings will be discarded.*

Here's an example to show these differences ([as seen on ideone.com](http://www.ideone.com/imSud)):

```
static void dump(String[] ss) {
    for (String s: ss) {
        System.out.print("[" + s + "]");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String text = "a-b-c-d---";

    dump(text.split("-"));
    // prints "[a][b][c][d]"

    dump(text.split("-", 2));
    // prints "[a][b-c-d---]"

    dump(text.split("-", -1));
    // [a][b][c][d][][][]
    
}
```

---

#### A partition that keeps the delimiter

If you need a similar functionality to the partition, and you also want to get the delimiter string that was matched by an arbitrary pattern, you can use [`Matcher`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html), then taking `substring` at appropriate indices.

Here's an example ([as seen on ideone.com](http://ideone.com/glvZ6)):

```
static String[] partition(String s, String regex) {
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(s);
    if (m.find()) {
        return new String[] {
            s.substring(0, m.start()),
            m.group(),
            s.substring(m.end()),
        };
    } else {
        throw new NoSuchElementException("Can't partition!");
    }
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    dump(partition("james007bond111", "\\d+"));
    // prints "[james][007][bond111]"
}
```

The regex `\d+` of course is any digit character (`\d`) repeated one-or-more times (`+`).

Comment: +1 for being the only correct answer to the question so far!  Additional imaginary +1 for the introduction to ideone, which looks very useful.

Comment: @Andrzej: yep, with ideone you can quickly (i) see that it works (ii) edit it and test it yourself

Answer (score 5):

While not *exactly* what you want, there's a [second version of split](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String,%20int)) which takes a "limit" parameter, telling it the maximum number of partitions to split the string into.

So if you called (in Java):

```
"foo bar hello world".split(" ", 2);
```

You'd get the array:

```
["foo", "bar hello world"]
```

which is more or less what you want, except for the fact that the separator character isn't embedded at index 1.  If you *really* need this last point, you'd need to do it yourself, but hopefully all you specifically wanted was the ability to limit the number of splits.

Comment: retaining the separator character is a requirement.

Comment: @sprocketonline: Ah, I see, I thought the array index was simply the separator *regex* (and thus trivial to splice in) but now I understand it's the sequence of characters that *matched* the regex (very different).  In which case, go with polygenelubricants' answer as the simplest way to do this is with explicit use of Matchers.

Comment: Doesn't work in chrome 48:
    "foo bar hello world".split(" ", 2);
    ["foo", "bar"]

Comment: @pbanka: That's because the Chrome console doesn't execute Java.  (The fact that this is also legal syntax in Javascript is a coincidence.)

Comment: @AndrzejDoyle – oh man, sorry. I misread the title of the thread.

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
String partition(String string, String separator) {
    String[] parts = string.split(separator, 2);
    return new String[] {parts[0], separator, parts[1]};
}
```

BTW, you have to add some input/result checks at this :)

Comment: separator argument to split is a regex

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
"foo bar hello world".split(" ",2)
```

By default the delimiter is whitespace

Comment: Read more carefully - this is not an answer to _this_ question.

Comment: this doesn't return the separator which is a requirement of the question.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there an external library which provides this utility already?

None that I know of.

> how would I achieve it without an external library?
>   And can it be achieved without an external library and without Regex?

Sure, that's no problem at all; just use `String.indexOf()` and `String.substring()`. However, Java does not have tuple datatype, so you'll have to return an array, List or write your own result class.